# Add extra control on custom UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to create custom UserControl so I can easily add some control so all control that implement CustomUserControl can affected.

This is what I do

```
public class CustomUserControl : UserControl
    {
        public CustomUserControl()
        {
            var stack = new StackPanel();
            stack.Children.Add(new TextBox() { Width = 100, Height = 100 });
            Content = stack; // need to add extra control to content
            //AddChild("test"); // this also fail
            //AddChild(stack); // this result in hard error
        }
    }
```

in the xaml

```
<control:CustomUserControl x:Class="Sample"
             xmlns:control="clr-namespace:Sample.Controls;assembly=Sample"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
            <TextBox Width="100" Height="100"/>
    </Grid>
</control:CustomUserControl>
```

I want it to show 2 textbox, but it only show one, maybe because content overrided by parent.

Comment: Obliviously, you are wrong at some points. You are changing the all content of usercontrol  then you are trying to add new texbox to a grid. I think you should reformulate your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But if you want to add it from code you to give a name to the grid, then add childs from code. For example XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid x:Name="MyGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="29*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="271*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="TextBox1 Text" Grid.Row="0"/>
</Grid>
```

And .cs file will be:

```
public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var textBlock2 = new TextBlock();
        textBlock2.Text = "TextBox2 Text";
        MyGrid.Children.Add(textBlock2);
        Grid.SetRow(textBlock2,1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor code is executing after XAML generation. Your content first setting to "Grid" in XAML, then "Content = stack" in .cs file. You need to set name to your grid in xaml and use it name in .cs file. But don't do it, please, use MVVM.

Comment: Is there's another way, I know UserControl that using CustomUserControl is override/replacing content that I set in CustomUserControl. But I kind of need that. I got a lot of UserControl but I need to add textbox control to it, and modifying all that UserControl is kind of violates dry since that control same on all UserControl also if I have to change something small like width of textbox, I have to do it all over again.

Comment: You can use [DataTemplates](http://www.wpftutorial.net/datatemplates.html). Just add DataTemplate for your textbox or UserControl and use it wherever needed. If you need to correct some propety, just change the Template for it in one place.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a custom user control with two text boxes in it, just do that in the control's XAML: you don't need to do it in the constructor.

In other words, delete your constructor:

```
public class CustomUserControl : UserControl
{
}
```

and get rid of the `Grid` in the XAML:

```
<control:CustomUserControl x:Class="Sample" ... >
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Width="100" Height="100"/>
        <TextBox Width="100" Height="100"/>
    </StackPanel>
</control:CustomUserControl>
```

Comment: I need to do it inside CustomUserControl because I got a lot of user control, ex: CustomerControl, ItemControl, etc but later I need to add extra control to both CustomerControl and ItemControl, so I kind of need to add it to CustomControl instead of in CustomerControl

Answer (score 0):

After digging UserControl and trial error I finally get what I want, just override on render in user control

```
protected override void OnRender(System.Windows.Media.DrawingContext drawingContext)
        {
            if (_group == null) //private field, hack so it only adding content once
            {
                var grid = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Vertical };
                _group = new WarningBoxControl();

                var content = Content as StackPanel;
                if (content != null)
                {
                    _group.DataContext = content.DataContext;
                    content.Children.Insert(0, _group);
                }
            }

            base.OnRender(drawingContext);
        }
```

The only problem with this is Control that implement CustomUserControl must have stack panel at its root. regardless this was easaier to maintain whenever I want to put extra control or something

Comment: `OnRender` is *not* the place to put code like this: the method is intended for custom drawing code, not for adding controls to the visual tree. If you really want to use the code you have posted above, then the best place for it would be in the constructor.

Comment: @StevenRands Yes but if I use it on constructor and use CustomUserControl in my CustomerUserControl it will get replaced by CustomerUserControl, but as you say adding control in this method looks so wrong, still don't know what bug this will spawn. any way I'm making CVVVLAD as answered question so no poor soul following this without knowing the consequences.